# How do I display MySQL data in rows?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a code in PHP to display MySQL database information. This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$servidor = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($servidor, "produtos");

if (isset($_GET['texto'])) {
    $pesquisa = $_GET['texto'];
    $query = mysqli_query($servidor, "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE Nome LIKE '%$pesquisa%' OR Referencia LIKE '%$pesquisa%'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<h3>Nome: ".$resultados['Nome']."</h3>Referência: ".$resultados['Referencia']."";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Não foram encontrados resultados!</h3>";
    }
}
?>
```

But right now, that information is displayed in one single line, like this:

[image]

and I want to display it in rows, like this:

[image]

How can I do this in PHP?

Thank you

Comment: Use modulus operator to check if the current row is divisible by 4 ,also add a div which holds 4 columns and if the row number is divisble by 4 add a close  and open div tag for the next row.Just a  hint since I see you don`t like to accept or upvote answers.

Comment: The major part is done in html

Comment: @Mihai ok....I like to accept or upvote but sometimes I forget to. Also, I would like to get my questions upvoted

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part can be achieved usign HTML + CSS as @Bernhard said. Or, something that I DON'T RECOMMEND, like this:

```
<div style="width:25%;float:left;padding:10px;">{item}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the new column attributes introduced by CSS 3.

Example:

```css
p {
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<body>
  <p>
    First column
  </p>
  <p>
    Second column
  </p>
  <p>
    Third column
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```